# Is it better to support a single language strings.xml or many languages, but badly?

Tags: android, internationalization

I have the patience to convert my strings.xml file and my HTML help files to other languages using Google Translation Toolkit.

However, the translations are not "100%" correct.

I speak German as well as English so used the Eng -> Ger translation for my strings.xml etc.

Some of the "gaffs" made by the translator were pretty bad.

So, is it better to have 1 language done well (ie English) or to also provide multi language support but for languages I have no idea about whatsoever.

I wanted to cover the "big boys" too such as Mandarin, Hindi, Japanese, Russian, etc but am worrying bad translations would make my app seem to be of a low quality.

Has anybody any experience and words of advice on the topic.

Many thanks.

Paul.

Comment: If you don't know how to do the translation, either do it partially, or don't do it at all. Of course bad translations will make your app look silly, possibly even offensive.

Comment: They are many opinions on the Web regarding "Is internationalization bad?" etc. It convinces me more and more everyday. Because for some apps, English is just well enough (plus it saves you time/money/time+money).

Answer (score 3):

You should probably hire translator(s) which are very good at the English and target foreign language(s).

One of the most important things is that translator must understand usage, concepts and conventions of your application - know it and understand it. Otherwise, you will end up with grammatically correct but meaningless translations in context of your app - I can see this in a lot of cases since my native language is not English.

And, yes, your app will look "low quality" and "hostile" to SOME people if it has translations that are missing the point.

Comment: To add to this -- releasing an application with a bad machine translation is *worse* than releasing an untranslated app, as there's no way for international users to get away from the mangled strings, even if they'd be able to understand the English version.

Answer (score 0):

German and English belong to the same language family and Google has ample data for both. Any other language, especially those that are linguistically a lot more distant (Chinese, Japanese, Hindi), is translated even worse than German. I do not believe that native speakers of these languages can get ANY value out of a machine translation.

Using a machine translation shows your foreign customers exactly how much value you place on them: none.

Answer (score 0):

Wow !.

It looks like a thumbs down then.

Like all things in life I suppose "compromise" is the winner.

My app basically has a single setup screen with about 15 strings and a few radio buttons, check boxes etc.

The games themselves are pretty obvious but underating the "gist" is better than no understanding at all.

I'll focus on getting the strings for the setup page "perfect" and add the HTML "help" screen translations with fingures crossed.

I am of the view that is one goes to a country one should at leasr learn some of the language. My experience is that the "natives" appreciate an "attempt to speak theor tongue" rather than simply assuming "they" should understand English. By the same philosophy, if the "main" points are translated well, I should at least earn a few more points for "having a go to respect their language and culture" by going through the translation process of "all supplied help text".

As I say, it is a tricky area to know what to do. If my app did take off I would not hesitate to have professional translations done but the initial outlay price for, say, 20 translations could well wipe out any return. In 2 months I'll be older and wiser (if only in expletives from people who are insulted by the translations).

I'd love to hear any other responses from people who have had the same dilemma and to know their real life "app" experiences in this area.

A genuine thankyou to those who have so far written..

Paul

Answer (score 0):

If your app is targeted at people who know english (geeks, system administrators, other computer people) then you better use english only UI.

Other way, if you target "common" audience you have to decide what do you want - bigger "client base" or higher app rating (because no annoyed people will rate your app 1 star because of bad l10n).

I'm russian myself and I can tell you that for me badly localized app is much more annoying than english app. But people who does not know english (there are a lot of them) will never install english-only app.